# How to make Pylons work in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, pylons

I am new to Pylons and GAE and was wondering if any team has had success with this combination. I have followed [this howto that is available on the web](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-monkey/wiki/Pylons) and have got it to work. But after I have everything working I cannot even create a controller. I have also gone through [this](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-monkey/issues/detail?id=22) but still no results.

Also I want to able to put it in source control and allow other developers to work with it. So far it seems everything is tied to the location where I have my pylons application. Has a TEAM developed using Pylons + GAE?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the steps described [here](http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonscookbook/Creating+a+Pylons+application+for+Google+App+Engine) and got it to work without a problem.

Comment: The recommended steps outlined at your link leads me to the howto that I had followed. Did you follow the old howto which is also listed there? Are you using Pylons and GAE in a team environment with a version control system? Were you able to use paste to create a controller?